# objc - white space between table view header and refresh control

Tags: objective-c, tableview

I'm creating a table view and assigning a header and a refresh control to them both of color lightBlue.

When I pull the refresh control down.. you can see a white line between the header and the refresh control.. it's bigger at first and then gets smaller that's why I couldn't get a good picture.

[image]

```
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];

    self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;

    self.tableView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive;
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.bannerView;
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
```

I already tried setting the actual view that gets added the tableViews background color to light blue but that doesn't do a thing.

Comment: If I change the tableview background color to light blue then it works but I want the bottom of the table view to remain white. Any ideas?

Comment: did you use view hierarchy debugging to find out what that white thing is?

Comment: Seems like it's the UITableViewWrapperView... which means if like I said I change the background of the tableview it works but would I be able to add maybe a subview to the back of the uitableview and have it near the top in order for this not to happen?

Comment: have you tried providing transparent or solid `UITableView.backgroundView`? I am sure that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This white line on my view can be 2 things.

1) Is just a simulator pixel problem, happens a lot with me, and then i just test in my device and works perfect.

2) Maybe your `self.bannerView` has a botton constraint or a single line, and this can produce this small white line.

my advise is, set the backgound color to be clear color and check if `self.bannerView` doens't have any small margin or single line

like:

```
[self.tableView.tableHeaderView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```